# Architecture for a .NET platform with Rest API

Tags: .net, ios, web-services, rest, architecture

I have a .NET platform that I need to expose to different clients (ASP.NET MVC, iOS and Android), I will be developing these clients myself not a third party.

Currently I have a business layer which executes some logic and persists data using entity framework into a SQL DB, what I am thinking now is to have the ASP.NET MVC client access the business layer direct and have the other (non .NET) clients consume the business layer using a REST API, is this a good approach? or do I need to make all the client access biz functionality using the service layer.

Answer (score 0):

First, very good question!, for me, I use ASP.NET MVC to access Service Layer, and this is not the layer that exposed to (non.NET) but this the layer that under that layer, I will describe to you why you will need service layer in MVC, one of the aspect of good design in MVC (Thin Controller) and to do this, you will need service layer, otherwise the Controller will be the victim, so you can use it for both.

Comment: Please when you down vote, leave a comment to help me and the community why you really consider this as a bad answer and what's is your good one!?

Answer (score 0):

You have some business logic, or functionality, that you want to offer to clients. These clients are: human users that will get access through a ASP.NET app (html/js/css UI) and other applications that will get access through an web API. Right?

The MVC part and the web API part are interfaces, this is translators, that transform clients' requests to business logic invocation and then transform back results to HTML/js/ccs for users or xml/json/whatever to client applications.

The real problem is in the way that you express the concepts, you are **NOT** *making your ASP.NET MVC client access the business layer directly and have the other (non .NET) clients consuming the business layer using a REST API*! What you are doing **is providing two interfaces**, one for human interaction and other for client applications interaction.

Your approach is okay.